# Certain cells dont have the correct gap bwtween them in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css-tables

What I have is a table, and in this table there are numerous collapsible panels. Now on all of the cells, bar two of them, the gaps in between each cell is the same. But in two specific ones, they are too small. I don't know what the difference is, can someone help me please.

The table:

http://codepad.org/HsfbEjNz

The cells which the gaps are out on are the first one and the ninth one.

right I have narrowed it down to when I expand the panels, the gaps go to the size I want, but before expanding them they are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Right i solved it I used this in my css file

```
.collapsePanelHeader 
    { 
        border: 1px solid #333333; 
        color: #333333; 
        background-color: #e5e5e5; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        padding: 5px; 
        cursor: pointer; 
    } 


    .collapsePanel 
    { 
        background-color: #ffffff; 
        overflow:hidden; 

        border-top: none; 
        padding: 2px; 
    } 


    .alignRight 
    { 
        text-align: right; 
        float: right; 
    }
```

And then referenced it like this on my asp:panel decleration:

```
 CssClass="collapsePanel"
```